# Is there an efficient way to find the lowest price from a group of products?

Tags: python

I have a shopping list for the products I want and a list of products from different vendors. 
Not every vendor has all the products I want and ordering from any vendor means shipping fees.

*I have a list of products that you want certainly to purchase; and want the lowest price in the sense that I want to choose the vendors such the price is lowest for that list of product.*

I would like to buy Magic the Gathering Boosters but there is no single vendor who has all of them on mkm. So I downloaded a list of all the product from all the vendors selling any one of the boosters I want. Now I have a sqlite database with 577 products in them but don't know how to find the cheapest combination of vendors and boosters.  I have tried the following code but am running into memory issues. Is there a way to solve this problem more efficiently?

classes:

```py
class Booster:

    def __init__(self, booster_id, seller, price, country):
        self.booster_id = booster_id
        self.seller = seller
        self.price = price
        self.country = country


class BoosterList:

    def __init__(self, sellers, boosters, price):
        self.sellers = sellers
        self.price = price
        self.boosters = boosters

    def add_booster(self, booster):
        """creates a new list of boosters with a list of all past boosters"""
        self.price_new = self.price + booster.price
        self.boosters_new = self.boosters + [booster]
        if booster.seller not in self.sellers:
            self.sellers_new = self.sellers + [booster.seller]
            self.price_new += shipping[booster.country]
        else:
            self.sellers_new = self.sellers
            self.price_new = self.price
        return BoosterList(self.sellers_new, self.boosters_new, self.price_new)
```

and the search algorithm:

```py
    def find_min_price(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect(self.db_location)
        c = db.cursor()

        booster_list_list = [BoosterList([], [], 0)]
        self.booster_list_list_new = []


        #finds the booster_ids of all the wanted boosters
        booster_ids = c.execute('select product_id from booster_info').fetchall()


        #finds all the products for all the boosters_id where vendors have more than 5 different boosters
        for booster_id in booster_ids[16:23]:
            print(booster_id, len(booster_ids))
            articles = c.execute("""select * from articles where
                                 product_id = ? and user_id in
                                (select user_id from articles 
                                 where country is not 'CH'
                                 group by user_id 
                                 having count(user_id)>5
                                 order by count(user_id)) """, booster_id).fetchall()

            for article in articles:
                booster_id = article[0]
                price = article[2]
                user_id = article[3]
                country = article[5]
                booster = Booster(booster_id, user_id, price, country)

                #adds every found booster to the booster list/creates a new one 
                for booster_list in booster_list_list:
                    self.booster_list_list_new.append(booster_list.add_booster(booster))
            booster_list_list = self.booster_list_list_new
            self.booster_list_list_new = []

        db.close()
        return booster_list_list
```

When running this code it works like a charm but requires way too much memory. Is there a more memory efficient way of finding the lowest price?

Comment: Hello @Stümperhacker - I am not sure if that is really a knapsack problem description because you have a specific list of products beforehand already. It is not about choosing a list of products so that a certain condition is met. Rather you have a list of products that you want certainly to purchase; you want the lowest price in the sense that you want to choose the vendors such the price is lowest for that list of product. I hope I did not misunderstand. Otherwise I suggest you update your question so that it may be less confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much for that suggestion, I have edited the question

Comment: One suggestion I have is that you could improve on the number of SQL query submissions: You execute an SQL statement in the for loop, say n time. You should look for a way to do that in one SQL query (e.g. `product_id in (....)`). You would have to rewrite your program, though there are chances that this can improve the execution time and the memory consumption.

Comment: The biggest memory consumption I currently have are the huge lists of boosters. As there are 577 of them there are about 200! lists in the end with 25 entries each. So about 10^250 lists

Comment: Oh dear, huge numbers. I am not sure if I understand, maybe it helps to describe that too ? I understand you have 577 boosters, but the rest gets me lost. How many vendors do you have or why so many lists ? Did you really write `200!` (i.e. Factorial) ?

Comment: there are 25 different boosters and 25 different vendors. Since not every vendor has all boosters so there are still a lot of possibilities left to arrange the boosters from different vendors. 25 vendors for the first booster, 20 vendors for the second booster, so just two different boosters give 500 lists. Then 20 again gives 10'000. down the line it will be a huge number of lists and my 12 GB of Ram is not enough. usually I only can get 8 levels deep.

Comment: How much are the shipping costs compared to the actual purchase price? I have to wonder how much of a difference there will be between an optimal solution and a hand-picked feasible solution. Consider this simple greedy solution: buy each item from the vendor that sells it for the least. A lower bound on the optimal solution would be to compute the shipping costs as if you were actually purchasing every item from the vendor with the cheapest shipping. Now: what's the difference between the lower bound and the greedy solution?

Comment: shipping is about twice the cost of a single booster so its quite a lot. Though your idea helped to me to reduce the number of 4 vendors and then the algorithm worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used chepners idea and reduced the number of vendors to 4 possible ones and then ran the algorithm. Now I have a solution and hope it is close to the low minimum.